# android-php ,response is triggered twice sometimes

Tags: php, android

I am using json response which connects to http://example.com/test.php I receive response in the listview and its all good,but sometimes the php is triggered  twice , eg: if has mail() function inside it sends once but rarely sends it twice ,I cannot predict when that is happening ,Is it because it does not contain session_start() or is it some other reason? The php has just mail() function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like a bug in Your android application activity code. Show us Your code where You handle the click event that connects to Your PHP script or we are not able to help You.

Comment: Its not a bug in android ,I guess its in PHP as it works well all the time its the same php, same code which loads the messages in the listview.

Comment: Hi Rajesh its the normal php with the mail() function called once no loops no condition.I am not using the session_start in php,I have another php which echo's array of strings.Which works fine but echo's twice rarely (Its the same PHP)